# dSLR holster on a belt OK?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag

I'm planning to use a modular belt system on vacation and outings. Last weekend I tried putting a lens changer and flash on my left side and kept the camea on a Backrapid strap hanging on my right.

I think I want a "holster" for better protection and containment, but:

- will that get in the way when the camera is "out"?
- is it too heavy to keep on a belt?

Using a simple clip (how to attach it at the same time as the strap?) will prevent the cameara from swinging,  but doesn't offer protection and getting out of a sudden rain. But, are there any other alternatives along that line?

---

### Inventory

- Canon 70D body
- EFS 17-55 f/2.8 normally attached
- lens changer pouch for EFS 55-250 f/(4-5.6)
- pouch with flash
- "Nifty fifty" lens
- collaping monopod
- screen hood loupe to see in sunlight and/or without reading glasses
- drink container
- extra battery,  memory cards

### Bags

I currently have a Lowepro [S&F Light Utility Belt](http://store.lowepro.com/s-f-light-utility-belt) and am using a lens changer pouch and flash pouch that goes with that system. 
I'm eyeing the [ThinkTank Holster 20](http://www.thinktankphoto.com/products/digital-holster-20-v2.aspx). ThinkTank modular bags can attach by going around the entire outer part of the segment, rather than through a loop on that segment. I've done that with their StuffIt pouches.

The Lowepro modular pouches don't have outer pockets or additional attachment points, and they don't make a holster for the modular system. That's one thing that made me wonder if it's impractical to put it on a belt.

Answer (score 1):

I've for years been using a LowePro beltpack camerabag. Works great. But it's a personal preference of course, see for yourself if it's what you want/need.
[LowePro Toploader Pro](http://www.lowepro.com/toploader-pro)
Another option (or combine with the Toploader would be the [Street&Field series](http://www.lowepro.com/sfseries) belt with pouches.


The 55-250 might get a bit uncomfortable banging against your leg. Apart from that, I'd not expect trouble. the belts are wide enough to comfortably distribute several kilos of weight. Using the Toploader I can carry a D200 with 70-200 f/2.8 attached and some cleaning kit, spare batteries and CF cards in the front pocket, plus a half liter bottle of water and a monopod around for hours with no problems.

Comment: About the Loewpro toploader... the pictures (http://store.lowepro.com/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/1160x1160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/l/tlp_70aw_ii_back.jpg) show a mesh-covered back. Where's the S&F attachment loop?

Comment: The 55-250 is smaller than the fast 17-55 actually.  How do you carry the monopod? The holster it came with is a plain belt loop which won't go on a modular belt, and the times I've used it, it gets in the way esp. to sit down.

Comment: @JDługosz the Toploader doesn't attach to the S&F system. It does itself have 2 loops for attaching S&F lens pouches on the sides. Mine comes with a belt of its own (see http://store.lowepro.com/media/wysiwyg/lowepro/product/ToploaderPro_shoulder-belt_half.jpg ) and I think you can loop another belt between the mesh and the case proper.

Comment: So, are you using it *on a belt*, with no other harnessing?

Comment: @JDługosz I just hook it its carrying strap to one of the rings on the bag. Hardware stores and outdoors shops have things like carabiners https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickdraw which are just perfect.

Comment: @JDługosz the belt and shoulder strap that come with it make for harnessing.

Comment: @JDługosz hook the strap of the monopod to a ring on the bag using a carabiner.

Comment: So you're *not* using a holster attached to a modular belt system, supported only with the belt and not a shoulder strap.

Comment: @JDługosz I usually use the shoulder strap because the whole thing gets rather heavy otherwise.